# How can I split my file containing file names and information into multiple files separately?

Tags: python, regex, file, awk, split

I have a `file.txt` that looks like this (I removed lines to simplify my example):

```
PLXNA3                                                                                     ### <- filename1
Missense/nonsense : 13 mutations                                                           # <- header spaces
accession   codon_change    amino_acid_change                                              # <- column names tsv
ID73        CAT-TAT         His66Tyr                                                       # <- line tsv
ID63        GAC-AAC         Asp127Asn                                                      # <- line tsv
ID31        GCC-GTC         Ala307Val                                                      # <- line tsv
NEDD4L                                                                                     ### <- filename2
Splicing : 1 mutation                                                                      # <- header spaces
accession      splicing_mutation                                                           # <- column names tsv
ID51           IVS1 as G-A -16229                                                          # <-  line tsv
Gross deletions : 1 mutation                                                               # <- header spaces
accession   DNA_level   description                 HGVS_(nucleotide)   HGVS_(protein)     # <- column names tsv
ID853       gDNA        4.5 Mb incl. entire gene    Not yet available   Not yet available  # <- line tsv
OPHN1                                                                                      ### <- filename3
Small insertions : 3 mutations                                                             # <- header spaces
accession         insertion                            HGVS_(nucleotide)                   # <- column names tsv
ID96          TTATGTT(^183)TATtCAAATCCAGG c.549dupT    p.(Gln184Serfs*23)                  # <- line tsv
ID25          GTGCT(^310)AAGCAcaG_EI_GTCAGTTCT         c.931_932dupCA                      # <- line tsv
```

I would like to split this file to obtain 3 different files:

`PLXNA3.txt`

```
PLXNA3                                                                                     ### <- filename1
Missense/nonsense : 13 mutations                                                           # <- header spaces
accession   codon_change    amino_acid_change                                              # <- column names tsv
ID73        CAT-TAT         His66Tyr                                                       # <- line tsv
ID63        GAC-AAC         Asp127Asn                                                      # <- line tsv
ID31        GCC-GTC         Ala307Val                                                      # <- line tsv
```

`NEDD4L.txt`

```
NEDD4L                                                                                     ### <- filename2
Splicing : 1 mutation                                                                      # <- header spaces
accession      splicing_mutation                                                           # <- column names tsv
ID51           IVS1 as G-A -16229                                                          # <-  line tsv
Gross deletions : 1 mutation                                                               # <- header spaces
accession   DNA_level   description                 HGVS_(nucleotide)   HGVS_(protein)     # <- column names tsv
ID853       gDNA        4.5 Mb incl. entire gene    Not yet available   Not yet available  # <- line tsv
```

`OPHN1`

```
OPHN1                                                                                      ### <- filename3
Small insertions : 3 mutations                                                             # <- header spaces
accession         insertion                            HGVS_(nucleotide)                   # <- column names tsv
ID96          TTATGTT(^183)TATtCAAATCCAGG c.549dupT    p.(Gln184Serfs*23)                  # <- line tsv
ID25          GTGCT(^310)AAGCAcaG_EI_GTCAGTTCT         c.931_932dupCA                      # <- line tsv
```

How can I achieve this desired output using any linux commands like `awk` or `python` ?

**Note:**

- filenames does not have any spaces or tabs but they may include `-`.
- header contains spaces.
- lines are tab separated.
- the real separator should be the filenames since I can have multiple headers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all lines except the filename lines contain either spaces or tabs?

Comment: @slin yes it is guaranteed.

Comment: Does a given file name, e.g. `NEDD4L`, ever repeat in the input or does it only occur once?

Comment: @EdMorton it only occur once since it's a gene name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NF==1{filename=$0 ".txt"};{print > filename}' file.txt
```

An equivalent but even more golfy option would be

```
awk 'NF==1{f=$0".txt"}{print>f}' file.txt
```

Comment: I am always impressed with what `awk` can do... thanks for the answer !

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, it is wonderful how such a non-trivial task can be collapsed in a single line with awk.

Comment: Unless you're using GNU awk that would fail with a "too many open files" error after it's created a dozen or so output files. If you want it to be portable and work for large sets of output files then you need to `close()` them as you go: `'NF==1{close(filename); filename=$0 ".txt"} {print > filename}'`

Comment: @EdMorton not sure what you mean by "portable" but I had no problem since it created 1753 files...

Comment: @Zen by portable I mean "would work with other awks". Right now you must be using GNU awk since it didn't fail, but if you try to use your script on some other platform or some other awk on your current platform then it will fail. All you need to do to avoid that possibility is close() the output files as  you're done with them as I showed in my comment.

Comment: @EdMorton oh ok ! Thanks for explaining !

Answer (score 1):

So here's the solution I came up with. It first opens the file you want to split up. Then it reads in the first line which is the filename for the first file. Let me skip the while loop for now. It opens a new file with the filename that was just  read in (strip() is necessary to get rid on the new line character at the end of the line). Then reads lines in and writes them to the new file until one comes, which has no space or tab in it. Then the process is repeated until the file has no more lines to read (the while loop I skiped earlier).

Hope it helps :)

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")

new_filename = file.readline()
while new_filename:
   with open(new_filename.strip() + ".txt", "w") as new_file:
      new_file.write(new_filename)
      line = file.readline()
      while " " in line or "\t" in line:
         # still the same new file
         new_file.write(line)
         line = file.readline()
   # file ended so read in line was the filename of the next file
   new_filename = line

file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposed answer ! I'd still go with `awk` since it is a one line command.